# React Native - FlatList unable to reach bottom

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard, scrollview

I have a panel in which the keyboard is always up since I do not wish the users to dismiss it. In that panel I have a FlatList which looks like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
         // This keeps the keyboard up and disables the user's ability to hide it.
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
         data={this.state.examples}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         renderItem={this._renderItem}
         contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1}}
      />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

So far so good, I have achieved what I wanted. However, when the keyboard is up - it hides the bottom part of the items rendered by the FlatList. And users cannot scroll up and view the last items because they stay behind the keyboard.

How can I preserve the Keyboard opened (and disable the ability to be dismissed) whilst being able to view and scroll through the whole content of the FlatList?

Comment: Can you tried to add   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   to your activity tab into your androidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @Kornflexx I am experiencing this on iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a keyboard listener event to get the height of the keyboard.

```
this.keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (e) => {
  this.setState({ keyboardHeight: e.endCoordinates.height, keyboardShow: true })
  Animated.timing(this.visibleHeight, {
    duration: e.duration,
    toValue: 1,
    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease)
  }).start()
})
```

View code like this

```
<Animated.View style={Platform.OS === 'android' ? { flex: 1 } : {
      height: this.visibleHeight.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [height - this.NavHeaderHeight, height - this.state.keyboardHeight - this.NavHeaderHeight]
      })
    }
    } >
     /*Your FlatList*/
</Animated.View>
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: I just managed to implement your suggestion. Worked as a charm!

Comment: What is this.NavHeaderHeight and how can use this in functional component.

Comment: @Nitish It's just a variable. You can define it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I've been to a similar situation. I had a bottom Floating Action Button at the lower right corner, hiding the last item a bit.

So, I added a **fake blank item to the end of the list** so that I could scroll it up a bit more.

It's simple and tricky. I hope it works for you as well, if you add a few blank itens or one wide enough blank item.

**EDIT 1:**

Suppose your data array is something like this: `[{title: "Item 1"}, {title: "Item 2"}]`

You have to concat the new blank item to the data array while passing it to the `<FlatList>`, like this:

```
<FlatList
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
   data={this.state.examples.concat({title:"\n\n\n\n\n"})}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   renderItem={this._renderItem}
   contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1}}/>
```

Adjust the amount of "\n" until you can scroll the list to be visible. There must be a minimum amount. And make sure your `_renderItem` don't set the item hight to a fixed value.

Comment: Do you think you can maybe provide me with an example of integrating this to my code above?

Comment: Thank you! I think this solution is kinda hacky since my project would work on different screen sizes which would require different amount of `/n` items manually added to the FlatList. I will still be looking for other alternatives but if no others are found I will mark your answer as solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda hacky. To be precise, you could forget about setting `"\n"`s and set the height if this last fake item to `max(0, list.height - keyboard.height)`.